# count each element in list without .count

Tags: python, list, count

For this function,I want to count each elements' occurrences and return a dict.
such as: [a,b,a,c,b,a,c]
and return {a:3,b:2,c:2}
How to do that?

Comment: What does your code look like so far?

Comment: new_dict = {}
    count = 0
    index = 0
    for a in range(len(b)):
        if b[index] == b[index +1]:
            count += 1
            index += 1
            new_dict.update({a:count})
        return new_dict

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [Counter](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) then:

```
from collections import Counter
Counter( ['a','b','a','c','b','a','c'] )
```

Or [DefaultDict](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(int)
for x in lVals:
    d[x] += 1
```

OR:

```
def get_cnt(lVals):
    d = dict(zip(lVals, [0]*len(lVals)))
    for x in lVals:
        d[x] += 1
    return d
```

Comment: Thx. btw, can I just create a function without import anything?

Comment: Use a normal dictionary - if the value isn't in the dictionary, create it and then increment it.

Answer (score 1):

Use the built in class [Counter](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

```
import collections
collections.Counter(['a','a','b'])
```

Comment: Thx, but Artsiom answered first so I will use his answer :)

Answer (score 1):

you can use `dict.setdefault`:

```
In [4]: def my_counter(lis):
    dic={}
    for x in lis:
        dic[x]=dic.setdefault(x,0)+1
    return dic
   ...: 

In [5]: my_counter(['a','b','a','c','b','a','c'])
Out[5]: {'a': 3, 'b': 2, 'c': 2}
```

or `dict.get`:

```
In [10]: def my_counter(lis):
    dic={}
    for x in lis:
        dic[x]=dic.get(x,0)+1
    return dic
   ....: 

In [11]: my_counter(['a','b','a','c','b','a','c'])
Out[11]: {'a': 3, 'b': 2, 'c': 2}
```